# How to convert a function into a class to be used from any page

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, class

I have the following function which is accessible from one of my asp.net page:

```
/* QUERY TO RUN FROM ANY FUNCTION */
public void runQuery()
{
    strMainSql = @"SELECT
                CT.OBJECTID 'Object ID'
        FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT
        WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.OBJECTID = '" + s + "'";

    using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        scConn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand scComm = new SqlCommand(strMainSql, scConn))
        {
            sdrRead = scComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdrRead.Read())
            {
                /* CAN BE USED IN OTHER PAGES */
                strTaskName = sdrRead[1].ToString();
                strTaskDetail = sdrRead[2].ToString();
                strTaskStartDate = sdrRead[3].ToString();
                strIdentifier = sdrRead[4].ToString();
                strStatus = sdrRead[5].ToString();
                strDueDate = sdrRead[6].ToString();
                strIssueDate = sdrRead[7].ToString();
                strCompleted = sdrRead[8].ToString();
                strNotes = sdrRead[9].ToString();
                strProvider = sdrRead[10].ToString();
                strService = sdrRead[11].ToString();
                strCheckedDate = sdrRead[12].ToString();
                strCheckedStatus = sdrRead[13].ToString();
                strCheckedUser = sdrRead[14].ToString();
                strClient = sdrRead[15].ToString();

                hfMemoID.Value = sdrRead[16].ToString();
                hfObjectID.Value = sdrRead[0].ToString();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /* SPECIFIC TO THE PAGE ONLY */
    lblUser.Text = strCheckedUser;
    lblDateTime.Text = strCheckedDate;
    lblTaskName.Text = strTaskName;
    lblClient.Text = strClient;
    lblID.Text = strIdentifier;
    lblSvc.Text = strService;
    lblProvider.Text = strProvider;
    lblStat.Text = strStatus;
    lblDueDate.Text = strDueDate;
    lblDetail.Text = strTaskDetail;
    lblTaskIssue.Text = strIssueDate;
    lblStartDate.Text = strTaskStartDate;
    lblCompleted.Text = strCompleted;
}
```

The question I have is, if I have to use the above function in multiple pages, instead of having a multiple copies of the same function which might lead to issue later on when updating, how do I make it into a class by itself so I can call it from any page and get the value from the SQL query?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. What's your problem with putting it in another class and calling it from there? Have you tried anything? And do you want to update the controls on this page when you call it somewhere else or are you just trying to run the query and get the non-page-specific strings?

Comment: I just want to get the query result back for the "class" I will be converting to. The `lbl??????` assignment will be done at page level.

Comment: Is this embedded on an aspx page or in the aspx.cs code behind file?

Comment: It is in my aspx.cs file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is expose the results from the query as properties and then use the properties in the ASPX page.

```
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace MyNamespace
    {
        public class Task
        {

            public string strTaskName { get; set; }
            public string strTaskDetail { get; set; }
            public string strTaskStartDate { get; set; }
            public string strIdentifier { get; set; }
            public string strStatus { get; set; }
            public string strDueDate { get; set; }
            public string strIssueDate { get; set; }
            public string strCompleted { get; set; }
            public string strNotes { get; set; }
            public string strProvider { get; set; }
            public string strService { get; set; }
            public string strCheckedDate { get; set; }
            public string strCheckedStatus { get; set; }
            public string strCheckedUser { get; set; }
            public string strClient { get; set; }

            // you need to define properties for the appropriate datatype on these
            //hfMemoID
            //hfObjectID

            public string strConn { get; set; }

            public void Load(string objectid)
            {
                var strMainSql = @"SELECT
                    CT.OBJECTID 'Object ID'
            FROM HSI.RMOBJECTINSTANCE1224 CT
            WHERE CT.ACTIVESTATUS = 0 AND CT.OBJECTID = '" + objectid + "'";

                using (SqlConnection scConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
                {
                    scConn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand scComm = new SqlCommand(strMainSql, scConn))
                    {
                        var sdrRead = scComm.ExecuteReader();
                        while (sdrRead.Read())
                        {
                            /* CAN BE USED IN OTHER PAGES */
                            this.strTaskName = sdrRead[1].ToString();
                            this.strTaskDetail = sdrRead[2].ToString();
                            this.strTaskStartDate = sdrRead[3].ToString();
                            this.strIdentifier = sdrRead[4].ToString();
                            this.strStatus = sdrRead[5].ToString();
                            this.strDueDate = sdrRead[6].ToString();
                            this.strIssueDate = sdrRead[7].ToString();
                            this.strCompleted = sdrRead[8].ToString();
                            this.strNotes = sdrRead[9].ToString();
                            this.strProvider = sdrRead[10].ToString();
                            this.strService = sdrRead[11].ToString();
                            this.strCheckedDate = sdrRead[12].ToString();
                            this.strCheckedStatus = sdrRead[13].ToString();
                            this.strCheckedUser = sdrRead[14].ToString();
                            this.strClient = sdrRead[15].ToString();

                            // 
                            //hfMemoID.Value = sdrRead[16].ToString();
                            //hfObjectID.Value = sdrRead[0].ToString();

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code behind use the class to load the data and then set the controls using the properties

```
    private MyNamespace.Task Task = new MyNamespace.Task();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.strConn = "my connection string.";
        Task.Load("task id to load");

        // set the value into the controls.
        lblUser.Text = Task.strCheckedUser;
        lblDateTime.Text = Task.strCheckedDate;
        lblTaskName.Text = Task.strTaskName;
        lblClient.Text = Task.strClient;
        lblID.Text = Task.strIdentifier;
        lblSvc.Text = Task.strService;
        lblProvider.Text = Task.strProvider;
        lblStat.Text = Task.strStatus;
        lblDueDate.Text = Task.strDueDate;
        lblDetail.Text = Task.strTaskDetail;
        lblTaskIssue.Text = Task.strIssueDate;
        lblStartDate.Text = Task.strTaskStartDate;
        lblCompleted.Text = Task.strCompleted;
    }
```

Comment: I need the `var Task` to be global. How can I achieve it? Thanks. I have it working btw :)

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, What do you mean by "global"?

Comment: The `Task` variable needs to be assigned so that I can assign it once and use it anywhere within the page. For if I assign `var Task = new Task()` in Page_Load, I can't use `Task` variable outside.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, In that case just declare Task as a class field.  I updated the answer with this change.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out and accept your answer as soon as I know it is working!